# How can I increase size of item in form?

Tags: django, authentication, captcha, verification

So I have captcha form in django project and it seems kinda small. I wan't to make it bigger.
**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField

class MyForm(forms.Form):
   captcha=CaptchaField()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import MyForm

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
   if request.method=="POST":
      form=MyForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         print("success")
      else:
         print("fail")
   form=MyForm()
   return render(request,"captcha_project/home.html",{"form":form})
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form method="POST" novalidate>
         {% csrf_token %}
         {{ form.captcha }}
         <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

**So, basically I just want to make captcha form bigger**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html), you could use `CAPTCHA_FONT_SIZE` or `CAPTCHA_IMAGE_SIZE` by defining them in your `settings.py`.